# Only for Appium Inspector ,Failed to create session , Android SDK folder does not exist in Windows 10 but path is correct

Tags: appium, appium-android, appium-desktop

In 64-bit windows 10, I downloaded and installed Appium-Inspector-windows-2022.2.1. Also in system variables  I set the ANDROID_HOME and path correctly.

```
ANDROID_HOME= C:\Users\Sameera\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
path=C:\Users\Sameera\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools;C:\Users\Sameera\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools;C:\Users\Sameera\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools
```

[image]

After that I started Emulator via command line using adb commands  also   and Appium server(Appium-Server-GUI-windows-1.22.2) in GUI mode.

[[image]][1

However, when I tried to start Appium inspector, it throws,

> Failed to create session. An unknown server-side error occurred while
> processing the command. Original error: The Android SDK root folder '
> C:\Users\Sameera\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk' does not exist on the
> local file system. Read
> https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/variables for more
> details

However, it exists.

[image]

Comment: Switching to Node based appium server and changing appium:platformVersion= 7 in Appium Inspector, solved the issue. Also appium:appPackage=io.selendroid.testapp and appium:appActivityName=io.selendroid.testapp.HomeScreenActivity